# Git stuck in rebase "Cannot store" (may be submodule related)

Tags: git, git-submodules, rebase

I am trying to abort a rebase but it fails with the following:

```
$ git rebase --abort
warning: Failed to merge submodule Client (not checked out)
"git stash store" requires one <commit> argument
Cannot store
```

At this point my `git status` shows two changes:

```
    both modified:   Client
    both modified:   blah.js
```

Notably `blah.js` was an old file which had some rere resolutions in the past.  Perhaps my rebase had gone back too far!

If I commit the changes, or reset the changes, and then try to abort again, the same thing happens.

How can I escape?!

---

What I have tried:

```
$ trash .git/MERGE_RR
$ trash .git/rr-cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

What I should have tried:

```
$ trash .git/rebase-merge/
```

That successfully got me out of the rebase, and I could proceed with recovery.

Thanks all!